# Android Screen Capture from service without root

Tags: android

Hey ther i need a code to capture android screen from service and save it to sdcard. so what i want to do is create a service and when the proximity sensor is coverd capture the screen and save it sdcard

Comment: such code would be a major security issue, that's why it's not possible.

Comment: whiche one is security issue caputering screen form a service or caputering using proximity sensor?

Comment: a service captures the screen with bank details, e-mail address, password typing and upload to the service creator service.

Comment: can you provide some example code or reference websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screencapture on non-rooted device is possible. If you create an executable file using Android Ndk and then connect it to computer to start it using android adb, you will be able to access /dev/graphics/fb0 and do screencapture using the file.

That technique is used by a lot of non-root screencapture app on google pkaystore.